# A foreign key constraint fails when adding a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two pre-existing tables, `bar` (with 2 columns, `id` [int 11] and `name`) and `foo_bar` (with 3 columns, `id`, `foo_id` and `bar_id` [int 11]). (There's also a table `foo` but that's not relevant here.)

I want to add a migration to `foo_bar` so that when a row is deleted from `bar` it deletes the relevant row in `foo_bar`. This is my statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo_bar` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `bar`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But when I run this I get this error:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbn`.`#sql-1_10ad`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-1_10ad_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `bar` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Both `bar_id` and `id` on the `bar` table have the type of `int(11)`. `id` on the `bar` table is a primary key.

Comment: 1) Check your syntax by creating the 2 tables (no data) in a test environment and run the alter statement. 2) if 1 is okay then the problem is data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there is a foreign key `bar_id` which is referring to an `id` in the `bar` table which does not exist.  You may find it using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo_bar fb
LEFT JOIN bar b
    on fb.bar_id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

To fix the problem, you may either delete these problematical records from `foo_bar` or you can update them to point to parent rows in `bar` which actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that rows already exist that violate the constraint.  You can see if this is the case by running:

```
select fb.*
from foo_bar fb
where not exists (select 1 from bar b where b.id = fb.id);
```

If this is the case, then delete the offending rows and then try to add the constraint again.